# Need to tweak my FTS4 SQLite query

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

The query below doesn't work on Android and throws the following exception

> `Unable to use function MATCH in the requested context`

It is a pretty complicated query so I'm looking into ways of simplifying it. For info, this query works on the same database on my computer with the `sqlite-jdbc-3.715` driver

```
SELECT * FROM stop_times WHERE 
    departure_time  >= 1000-125
    AND 
    departure_time <= 1000+180 
    AND stop_id IN 
        (SELECT _id FROM stop_sequences WHERE stop_ids MATCH '"642," OR "642," OR ",642"')
    AND _id IN 
        (SELECT _id FROM trips WHERE service_id IN (SELECT _id FROM calendar WHERE wednesday=1))
ORDER BY departure_time ASC
```

I think my FTS table declaration is OK:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE stop_sequences USING fts4(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    stop_ids TEXT
);
```

Could an SQL guru help me out? Thanks

EDIT: I found out that even the simplest query such as

```
SELECT _id FROM stop_sequences WHERE stop_ids MATCH '"642";
```

fails with the same error. I already use `MATCH` statements on another database somewhere else in my code and it doesn't complain at all. Does the context mentionned in the error message has anything to do with Android's `Context`?

Comment: I think that would have a bad performance hit and my stopsequences table is quite large

Comment: sqlite does not have MATCH

Comment: Yes it does, I'm using it in another part of my app

Comment: You are right my mistake

Comment: You make want to take a look at this link http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/2010-03/msg00073.html

Comment: Could you please create a [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data? Makes it easier to find a solution.

Comment: Building my schema in Fiddle hangs as I think there's some unsupported sql modules that I use. I've uploaded my database here if you want to have a look https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qaid3ooi0huyeg/test.db Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's a dumb question, but `stop_ids TEXT` looks like it should hold foreign keys. If so, why don't you use an additional table to associate `n:n` relations?

Comment: No stop_ids holds an array of numbers separated by a ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created this table, you specified [USING fts4()](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2), right? If not, you're full-text queries will not work at all.

Comment: Yeah my CREATE is in the question. Also, this query works when I run it in my shell using sqlite3 command

Comment: Ok I'm really stupid, I was using an old version of the database that I forgot to update to the new one with the fts4 table. Your answer made me check so should I accept it?

Comment: Don't feel bad, @chopchop, we all have similar issues sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change query with union

```
SELECT * FROM stop_times WHERE 
    departure_time  >= 1000-125
    AND 
    departure_time <= 1000+180 
    AND stop_id IN 
        (SELECT _id FROM stop_sequences 
         WHERE stop_ids 
         MATCH '"642,"'
         UNION
         SELECT _id FROM stop_sequences 
         WHERE stop_ids 
         MATCH '",642"'
         )
    AND _id IN 
        (SELECT _id FROM trips WHERE service_id IN (SELECT _id FROM calendar WHERE wednesday=1))
ORDER BY departure_time ASC
```